# How to update two tables with a single MySql query?

Tags: mysql

I Have 2 Table "users" and "querys". Normally i use

```
INSERT INTO querys (row1,row2,row3) values(.....)
UPDATE users SET credit=credit-1 ......
```

I want to use one query.

Comment: you want to update two rows or two tables at one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write multiple statements using the semi-colon delimiter. Additionally, you can use a transaction to ensure that both statements execute in your batch.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO querys (row1,row2,row3) values('A', 'B', 'C');
UPDATE users SET credit=credit-1;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Stored Procedures` for a single query instead of trying to write very complex queries.